# What is the name of this colormap

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to know what is the name of this colormap

[image]

Comment: This colormap doesn't have a standard name, at least not in matplotlib.  If you'd had a better quality image, you could grab the colors and create a `ListedColormap` or a `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()` by grabbing the colors from the image.  Your question doesn't tell what exactly you want to do.  For example `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(['indigo', 'green', 'pink'])` would give something a bit similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't find it, make your own *colormap* and [`register`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ColormapRegistry.register) it :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(["#4a2199", "#5300a9", "#38289f", "#00708d",
                                  "#00996f", "#24a338", "#6faf15", "#b4ae00",
                                  "#f99700", "#faab1b", "#faa694", "#ffc4ac"])

mpl.colormaps.register(cmap, name="the_missing_cmap") # <-- change the name here
```

[image]